# CachyOS - Fastfetch configuration

Tags: arch-linux, configuration

I am using the fastfetch command in CachyOS. I would like the captions that are on the left to be in the middle. How to do it? My configuration file looks like this:

```
--separator ": "
--set-keyless HardwareStart=┌────────── \e[1mSystem Information\e[0m ──────────┐
--set-keyless InformationEnd=└────────────────────────────────────────┘
--structure HardwareStart:OS:Kernel:Shell:DE:Uptime:InformationEnd:Colors
--set-keyless Colors=            \e[38m \e[37m \e[36m \e[35m \e[34m \e[33m \e[32m \e[31m
```

I am a novice user of systems based on the arch family.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuXP9.png]

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you'll have to modify [`fastfetch`'s source code](https://github.com/fastfetch-cli/fastfetch), quite fundamentally.

From a glimpse at it, the way fastfetch works is that it parses your `--structure`, and makes a list of entries from that.

Then it goes into the template, checks the first line, `printf`s the first line of the distro logo, then `printf`s the first element of your structure list. Finally, it prints a line break.

Then it goes to the second line, prints the second line of the logo, then prints the second element of the structure list. Which itself consists of `printf`ing "`OS:` ", followed by `printf` of the detected OS (`CachyOS Linux x86_64`).

To center-align things, the logic would need to change: It would first have to measure how long the strings *would* be if printed, then prepend half the remaining space in the "box" to it, then actually print.

Because fastfetch isn't written that way: Go ahead and modify it! Instead of directly `printf` to console, you'd probably want to let it work on a character array buffer instead, and introduce layout/placement functions, much like you would if you were using an actual TUI framework, like `ncurses` or [`notcurses`](https://github.com/dankamongmen/notcurses). Sadly, that kind of requires significant rework of `fastfetch`'s source code.